# Import .rds file to h2o frame directly

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, dplyr, h2o

I have a large `.rds` file saved and I trying to directly import `.rds` file to h2o frame using some functionality, because it is not feasible for me to read that file in R enviornment and then use `as.h2o` function to convert. 
I am looking for some fast and efficient way to deal with it.

My attempts:

1. I have tried to read that file and then convert it into h2o frame. But, it is way much time consuming process.
2. I tried saving file in .csv format and using `h2o.import()` with `parse=T`.
   Due to memory constraint I was not able to save complete dataframe.

Please suggest me any efficient way to do it.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The native read/write functionality in R is not very efficient, so I'd recommend using **data.table** for that.  Both options below make use of **data.table** in some way.

First, I'd recommend trying the following:  Once you install the **data.table** package, and load the **h2o** library, set `options("h2o.use.data.table"=TRUE)`.  What that will do is make sure that `as.h2o()` uses **data.table** underneath for the conversion from an R data.frame to an H2O Frame.  Something to note about how `as.h2o()` works -- it writes the file from R to disk and then reads it back again into H2O using `h2o.importFile()`, H2O's parallel file-reader.

There is another option, which is effectively the same thing, though your RAM doesn't need to store two copies of the data at once (one in R and one in H2O), so it might be more efficient if you are really strapped for resources.

Save the file as a CSV or a zipped CSV.  If you are having issues saving the data frame to disk as a CSV, then you should make sure you're using an efficient file writer like `data.table::fwrite()`. Once you have the file on disk, read it directly into H2O using `h2o.importFile()`.